# Genitive Adjective with no Noun Referent

Tags: translation-check, latin-to-english-translation, syntax

> Praejudicium autem cum dico, non volo intelligi qualecunque praegressum judicium in animo; quasi animus ab omni omnino judicio liber esse debeat: sed judicium quod semel formatum **tanti** fit, ut eo quis stare velit, atque idcirco rationes omnes respuere quae isti labefactando idoneae sunt.

How would "tanti" be translated in this sentence? Also, how is my overall translation?

> But when I say prejudice, I do not want all preceding judgment whatsoever to be understood: as if the mind should be absolutely free from every judgment, but at least from a formed judgment made of such, that someone desires to remain therein, and on that account rejects all reasons which are apt to undermine it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Other than the phrase in question, your translation is excellent. *Tanti* is a so-called "genitive of indefinite value", see [Allen and Greenough section 417](http://dcc.dickinson.edu/grammar/latin/ablative-price). This is a use of adjectives expressing quantity in the context of a verb whose meaning can assign or assess value, as here *fit*: literally, "it (the judgment) becomes / is made **of such value** that...".

Note also that *semel* means "once". So the phrase in question can be translated "a judgment which, once formed, becomes of such great value", or less literally, "so important / weighty that...".